# How to get one random item from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I have an array below and I want to get one random item from it.

```
var = ["gm" , "hello" , "dance"," jump","clomb"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "Math.random" function, like sharing you a sample.

```
const random = ["gm" , "hello" , "dance"," jump","clomb"]
const randomName = (name) => {
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * name.length)
  return name[random]
}

console.log(randomName(random))
```

Also adding code snippet :

```js
const random = ["gm" , "hello" , "dance"," jump","clomb"]
const randomName = (name) => {
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * name.length)
  return name[random]
}

console.log(randomName(random))
```